# Why use the "finally" keyword?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I understand what the "finally" keyword is used for in various languages, however, I struggle to understand *why* you would use it outside of there being a formatting preference in taste.

For instance, in PHP:

```php
try {
  possibleErrorThrownFunction();
}
catch (CustomException $customException) {
  // handle custom error
}
catch (Exception $exception) {
  // handle the error
}
finally {
  // run this code every single time regardless of error or not
}
```

What's the difference between what this code is doing and this?

```php
try {
  possibleErrorThrownFunction();
}
catch (CustomException $customException) {
  // handle custom error
}
catch (Exception $exception) {
  // handle the error
}

// run this code every single time regardless of error or not
```

Doesn't that last line always get run anyway due to the error being caught? In which case, there is no case to really use `finally` unless you just want to maintain a code-style formatting?

An example of a case where a `finally` statement is necessary and distinct from just putting code after try/catch statements would be helpful if I am missing something here.

Comment: Finally will **always** be executed, if exception was thrown or not. This is often used for clean-up tasks like unlocking files or what the compiler (PHP) does not do itself.

Comment: As @MarkusZeller states, it's commonly used for cleanup.  Checkout the java docs for a good detail:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: @MarkusZeller php is interpreted, not compiled.

Comment: If you throw an exception that isn't handled by any of the catch clauses or if you throw an exception from within any of the handlers, then the code following the catch clauses will never be executed, while a finally block will get executed before the exception is further propagated down the call stack

Comment: @bassxzero Yes, the (PHP) code is interpreted, but in the end it is compiled to bytecode. That does not change the **finally** behavior.

Comment: @foobar in the example there is an explicit `catch (\Exception $e)` which catches all.. so this does not make a difference here.

Comment: @Kaii I just wanted to cover all cases where an exception might escape. For the op's specific example my 2nd statement still holds true, where throwing an exception from within one of the handlers will prevent execution of any code following it, unless it is placed within a finally block

Comment: `Finally` is there because sane people usually don't catch the base exception like that. And sometimes, even catch statement itself is not specified. In those cases, finally is the guaranteed way of executing the cleanup tasks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Short Answer

`Finally` blocks are guaranteed to run no matter what happens inside of the `try` and `catch` blocks, before allowing the program to crash.

This is sort of explained here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php though the explanation isn't particularly detailed.

## Some More Detail

One example that comes to the top of my head is if you are dealing with input/output streams or something similar that has to be closed after use in order to avoid a memory leak. To use your example:

```
try {
  memoryUser.startReading(someFileOrSomething);
}
catch (CustomException $customException) {
  // handle custom error
}
catch (Exception $exception) {
  // handle the error
  invisibleBug.whoops(); // i.e. something goes wrong in this block
}

memoryUser.Close(); // because something went wrong in the catch block,
                    // this never runs, which, in this case, causes a memory leak
```

In this case, wrapping the `memoryUser.Close();` in a `finally` block would ensure that that line would run before the rest of the program exploded, preventing the memory leak even in an otherwise catastrophic failure.

## TL;DR

So a lot of the time, people put the finally block there to ensure an important line runs, even if they overlooked something in the catch blocks. This is how I've always seen it used.

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you're conveying, the condition that I'm not seeing is when an error occurs in the catch statement(s); in which case a finally statement can still run despite a new, uncaught error arising? The implication being, that you _should_ in fact use finally statements since you can't always predict errors in catch statements?

Comment: Although the syntax appears to be Java, this is a good example and explanation.

Comment: Precisely :) Another possible exception for when you might not need a finally block could be if the catch is incredibly simple (like maybe `System.out.println("uh oh");` but it I usually just prefer being safe to sorry :)
  
@adam thank you and good eye. I am more familiar with Java, but figured that the concept would be the same.

Comment: "Finally blocks are guaranteed to run no matter what happens inside of the try and catch blocks". If PHP is like any other language (well that's a big if, but it generally isn't better than others) I seriously doubt that. Apart from the nitpicky endless loop scenarios, PHP does have an `exit` function, which I assume calls the C runtime's exit, which means the process is simply torn down and no finally block is executed. Same happens in .NET or Java.

Comment: @Jake - Sometimes you also DON'T write catch blocks. Like `try { ... } finally {... }`. Then the exception will get propagated upwards (caught in some other method which can handle it), but the `finally` block will run anyway cleaning up whatever needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: @Jake - And at other times, you don't _fully_ handle the exception. Like, you  do a little bit in your `catch` (maybe log it or add some details to the exception object), but then re-throw the exception so that some higher level can catch it and handle it properly. Again, `finally` cleans up.

Answer (score 27):

What's special about a `finally {}` block is that it will **always** run at the end of the `try {}` block.

- It will run if the code in the `try {}` block completes successfully.
- It will run if the code in the `try {}` block throws an exception that was caught by a `catch {}`. (The `finally {}` runs after the `catch {}`.)
- It will run if the code in the `try {}` block throws an exception that wasn't handled by any `catch {}` block, or if there weren't any at all. (The `finally {}` block runs before the exception is propagated to the caller.)
- It will run if the code in the `try {}` block throws an exception, and the code in the `catch {}` throws *another* exception (or rethrows the same exception).
- It will even run if the code in the `try {}` block, or in a `catch {}` block, uses `return`. (Just as with an uncaught exception, the `finally {}` runs before the function actually returns.) The `finally {}` block can even use `return` itself, and its return value will override the value that the other block tried to return!

(There is one edge case where a `finally {}` block won't run, and that's if the entire process is destroyed, e.g. by being killed, or by calling `exit()` or `die()`.)

Comment: To compare and contrast the two snippets in the question, it might be worth mentioning in which of these cases regular code after the `try/catch/finally` would run. (The first two? I'm not sure.)

Comment: @ilkkachu yes only in the first two.